# Inverse law of large numbers for groups?

Tags: probability, group-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose, $G$ is a finite group, $A$ is its finite symmetric set of generators. Let's define $\lVert g \rVert_A$ as the Cayley distance (in  respect to $A$) from $g$ to $e$.

Now, suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are i.i.d. random elements of $G$. Let's define a random walk on $G$ with step $X_i$ as the sequence of random elements $\{Z_n\}_{n = 0}^\infty$ defined by the recurrence:

$Z_n = \begin{cases} e & \quad n = 0 \\ Z_{n-1}X_n & \quad n > 0 \end{cases}$

It is known, that for the random walks on groups there is a following "Law of Large Numbers":

> If $E \lVert X_i \rVert_A < \infty$ then $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\lVert Z_n \rVert_A}{n} \overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}} \alpha$

Here $\overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}}$ stands for convergence in probability.

Note, that the $\alpha$ in this theorem (unlike the classical Law of Large Numbers) is generally not equal to $E \lVert X_i \rVert_A$. For example, $\alpha$ is always $0$ for finite $G$. However, the inequality $\alpha \leq E \lVert X_i \rVert_A$ always holds as a consequence of triangle inequality for Cayley metric.

My question is: Is the inverse statement also true? Namely:

> Does $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\lVert Z_n \rVert_A}{n} \overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}} \alpha$ always imply $E \lVert X_i \rVert_A < \infty$?

Comment: I don't get it. You're asking if the expectation of a non-negative random variable is at most $\infty$. Yes, trivially - the non-negativity gets rid of the only possible subtlety. Do you want to edit the statement a bit? (Also, aside, `\overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}}` = $\overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}}$ might be a nicer way to typeset $\to^p_{n \to \infty}$ )

Comment: @stochasticboy321, it should have been $< \infty$ not $\leq \infty$. Now I corrected this typo.

Comment: `\lVert` and `\rVert` produce the proper delimiters for the norm bars: `\lVert g\rVert_A` yields $\lVert g\rVert_A$.